# how to render array of component inside Text component in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I started a chat project in react native. And now I'm having a problem with showing emoji. I got data of message, extract it and save to array. This is an example of message and the array of it

```
abc :smile: xyz  
[
  <Text>abc </Text>,  
  <Image source={{uri:"SMILE_EMOJI_URL"}} />
  <Text> xyz</Text>
]
```

I will create a Text tag and put them all in as nested tags, so I just need to format one time. My expected result

```
<Text style={MY_STYLE}>
  <Text>abc </Text><Image source={{uri:"SMILE_EMOJI_URL"}} /><Text> xyz</Text>
</Text>
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can do this in react native.

Comment: why dont you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat

Answer (score 0):

your text-Component could look like this:

```
class ChatMessage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            message: ""
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var localMessage;
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfEmojiCodes.length; i++) {
            if (this.props.message.includes(arrayOfEmojiCodes[i])) {
                localMessage = this.props.message.split(arrayOfEmojiCodes[i])[0] + " <img src='"+arrayOfIconImages[arrayOfEmojiCodes[i]]+"' /> " + this.props.message.split(arrayOfEmojiCodes[i])[1];
                i = arrayOfEmojiCodes.length;
            } else {
                localMessage = this.props.message;
            }
        }
        this.setState({message: localMessage});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={this.props.style}>
                <p>{this.state.message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

then you can just call it:

```
<div className="chat">
    {['Message1 :smile', 'message2'].map((value, index) => {
        <ChatMessage key={index} message={value} />
    })}
</div>
```

You need to do some modification to your code to fit it your needs, but basically this should make it easier to handle the situation.